# Conversion from ETC to UTC timezone while loading from AWS S3 to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

is it possible to convert Timezone (ETC to UTC) while loading from S3 to Snowflake table, if yes please let suggest how we can do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake currently supports **CONVERT_TIMEZONE** for COPY transformations.

[COPY transformation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html) documentation here.

So for exemple if your data is in **1st column of your staged file** and the timezone in the file is **Etc/GMT+2**.

```
copy into mytable (my_field)
from (
  select
    convert_timezone('Etc/GMT+2', 'UTC', $1) as conv
  from @~/myfile.csv.gz t
)
;
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this approach and update here. Thanks!